# Example of Why Integration Order Is Not Always Interchangable

Tags: integration

I am being asked to find $\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy$ and $\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy\,dx$.  I am even told to "notice that" $\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

I can put both of these in my calculator to find the respective values are $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $-\frac{\pi}{4}$.  I have two problems...

1. I believe the "notice that" integral should be negative.  If it were taken with respect to $x$, then it would be positive.  Am I correct?
2. If I assume this piece of information, I know how to compute the rest using the an inverse trigonometric function.  The problem is I do not know why this is true.  I have tried factoring the difference of two squares and PFD, but that does not seem to help me.

Suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: 1.) yes
2.) $\int1/(1+x^2)dx=arctan(x)$

Comment: I understand that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1}=\arctan(x)$.  I do not understand how $\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: you are correct about the sign in your first question

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest proof here is found by noting that $\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}\arctan(y/x)$
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy$$
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}\arctan(y/x)\,dy$$
$$=\lim_{t \to \infty}\left.\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\arctan(y/x) \,dy\right)\right|_{y=1}^{y=t}$$
$$=\lim_{t \to \infty}\left.\left(\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)\right|_{y=1}^{y=t}$$
$$=\frac{-1}{x^2 + 1}$$
We can now easily integrate with respect to $x$ to get the result as claimed... note that the OP is correct though, the provided hint has the wrong sign. Note that this is an example of Fubini's theorem (and a function that violates it) and further info can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)